# Is there an "Explain RDD" in spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

In particular, if I say

```
rdd3 = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

then when I call `rdd3.collect`, depending on the `Partitioner` used, either data is moved between nodes partitions, or the join is done locally on each partition (or, for all I know, something else entirely). 
This depends on what the RDD paper calls "narrow" and "wide" dependencies, but who knows how good the optimizer is in practice.

Anyways, I can kind of glean from the trace output which thing actually happened, but it would be nice to call `rdd3.explain`.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think `toDebugString` will appease your curiosity.

```
scala> val data = sc.parallelize(List((1,2)))
data: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[8] at parallelize at <console>:21

scala> val joinedData = data join data
joinedData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Int, Int))] = MapPartitionsRDD[11] at join at <console>:23

scala> joinedData.toDebugString
res4: String =
(8) MapPartitionsRDD[11] at join at <console>:23 []
 |  MapPartitionsRDD[10] at join at <console>:23 []
 |  CoGroupedRDD[9] at join at <console>:23 []
 +-(8) ParallelCollectionRDD[8] at parallelize at <console>:21 []
 +-(8) ParallelCollectionRDD[8] at parallelize at <console>:21 []
```

Each indentation is a stage, so this should run as two stages.

Also, the optimizer is fairly decent, however I would suggest using `DataFrames` if you are using 1.3+ as the optimizer there is EVEN better in many cases:)

Comment: thats a thing of beauty

Comment: This is useful, but its not the level of detail I was hoping for.  In particular, a join requiring/not require a shuffle give the same toDebugString output... although for things like distinct I can clearly see the shuffle step.

Comment: I think I mean "realized to run local", as in, no data should be sent between nodes if the partitioners agree.

Comment: A lot of that is going to be runtime optimizations...that is the joy of lazy design and the DAG

Comment: You can check the partitioner though?

Comment: Its runtime optimized!?!?!?!
Ok, I think thats the answer I was looking for (unfortunately... but, uh, thanks?).
What do you mean by check the partitioner?  I've defined my own partitioner and I want to make the optimizer handle it.
Are parts of the optimizer exposed here?

Comment: There are definitely parts that are handled by the DAGScheduler -> https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/DAGScheduler.scala

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77555/discussion-between-justin-pihony-and-joseph-victor).

Answer (score 1):

I would use Spark UI (the web page the spark context used to serve) instead of `toDebugString` whenever I can. Much easier to comprehend, and a bit more information (and less glitches according my very limited experience). Also, Spark UI shows the number of Tasks and their input and output sizes for each Stage, which helps figuring out what it does.

Besides, there's very little information shown in both of them. Mostly just a graph of boxes saying `MapPartitionsRDD [12]` and such, which doesn't tell much about what that step actually does. (For `WholeStageCodegen` boxes the `DEBUG` log under `org.apache.spark.sql.execution` contains the generated code at least. But there's no any kind of ID logged to pair them with what you see on Spark UI.)