# How is task distributed in spark

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-system

I am trying to understand that when a job is submitted from the spark-submit and I have spark deployed system with 4 nodes how is the work distributed in spark. If there is large data set to operate on, I wanted to understand exactly in how many stages are the task divided and how many executors run for the job. Wanted to understand how is this decided for every stage.

Comment: Much of the way your application will run on Spark is configurable in the command line for spark submit, which includes the number of executors, nodes, etc: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question exactly, because there are many uncertainties.

Number of stages depends only on described workflow, which includes different kind of maps, reduces, joins, etc. If you understand it, you basically can read that right from the code. But most importantly that helps you to write more performant algorithms, because it's generally known the one have to avoid shuffles. For example, when you do a join, it requires shuffle - it's a boundary stage. This is pretty simple to see, you have to print `rdd.toDebugString()` and then look at indentation (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171129/is-there-an-explain-rdd-in-spark)), because indentation is a shuffle.

But with number of executors that's completely different story, because it depends on number of partitions. It's like for 2 partitions it requires only 2 executors, but for 40 ones - all 4, since you have only 4. But additionally number of partitions might depend on few properties you can provide at the spark-submit:

- spark.default.parallelism parameter or
- data source you use (f.e. for HDFS and Cassandra it is different)

It'd be a good to keep all of the cores in cluster busy, but no more (meaning single process only just one partition), because processing of each partition takes a bit of overhead. On the other hand if your data is skewed, then some cores would require more time to process bigger partitions, than others - in this case it helps to split data to more partitions so that all cores are busy roughly same amount of time. This helps with balancing cluster and throughput at the same time.